# Combining multiple Excel files in one excel in python

Tags: python, excel

What I need is how do I merge all these excel month wise .
    For example All July files must in one excel file in `July.xls` , 
    ALl september files should be in one excel file which is `september.xls` etc How do I do this can any body help and also if these files exceeds the range of excels then divide it into two excel files july_1 ,july_2.

I have multiple Excel files which are as follows  This are the input excel files

```
July_1_2017_00_23_59.xls
July_2_2017_00_23_59.xls
July_3_2017_00_23_59.xls
July_4_2017_00_23_59.xls
July_5_2017_00_23_59.xls
August_1_2017_00_23_59.xls
August_2_2017_00_23_59.xls
August_3_2017_00_23_59.xls
August_4_2017_00_23_59.xls
August_5_2017_00_23_59.xls
september_1_2017_00_23_59.xls
september_2_2017_00_23_59.xls
```

Please help me do this in python.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @Harsha  I dont know  How do i start so I am stucked up

Comment: To get started you need to start looking into pandas module.

Answer (score 0):

First you can group your files by month to know the ones which you should merge together. If your files have the format you mentioned, you can do that quickly using defaultdict and split(). Assuming `documents` contains the list of your files:

```
from collections import defaultdict

months = defaultdict(list)

for document in documents:
    month = document.split('_')[0]
    months[month].append(document)
```

Then all you have to do is iterate through the dictionary and read the excel files and concatenate them using pandas. I haven't tested the code below, but it should give you a rough idea of how to proceed.

```
import pandas as pd
for month in months:
    for i, document in enumerate(month):
        if i == 0:
            base_document = pd.read_excel(document)
        else:
            base_document = pd.concat([base_document, pd.read_excel(document)])
    base_document.to_excel(month + '.xls')
```

Regarding handling "files [that] exceeds the range of excels", I am unsure what you mean, you ought to give us more details.